# Is there a preference between writing complex numbers as $z=a+bi$ or $z=a+ib$?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

This is probably just a minor notational issue, but I am unsure whether I should write $z=a+bi$ or $z=a+ib$ when denoting complex numbers. Though the former notation seems more common, Euler's identity tends to be written as
$$
e^{i\pi}+1=0
$$

where the exponent is written as $i\pi$, not $\pi i$. I don't doubt that they mean the same thing, but I was wondering if one of the notations is more readable than the other. Perhaps someone can explain this apparent discrepancy between how we write $z$, and how we write $e^{i\pi}$.

Comment: I thought that the latter notation was more common :p

Comment: No importance. It may happen that in the spelling of some langages, one of them is more appealing to the ear...

Comment: The end result is that it is largely personal preference and there are no strict rules.  It is particularly uncommon in my personal experience to see $i2$ rather than $2i$ (*though that may largely be because of my limited interactions with others with varying views*), but beyond real numbers who are represented in decimal format, you might see all other terms in the product in many different orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, $z=a+bi$ is used when b is a constant (for example $4+3i$) and $z=a+ib$ when b is a variable (for example $x+iy$).  When b has both variable and constant components, the i appears between them (for example $7+3ix$)

Comment: That makes sense, and is also what the answerers wrote in the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$bi=b\cdot i=i\cdot b=ib$, so there is no difference. But it's more common to write $a+ib$.

Since the sum is commutative, you can also write $bi+a$ or $ib+a$, it's all the same.